# i am using ajax but it show method not support i check but method is same in ajax and in route

Tags: laravel

I am trying this but it show me this
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
**Route**
'''

```
Route::get('/','EmployeeController@index');
Route::post('employee.store','EmployeeController@store')->name('employee.store');
```

'''
**Ajax**
'''

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#insert_form').on('submit',function(e){
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax
({
type:"POST",
url:"{{route('employee.store')}}",
data:new FormData(this),
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data)  
{
alert();
window.location.reload();
}
});
});
})
```

'''

**blade**
'''

```
<form action="" id="insert_form" method="post">
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">                           
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

Pls modify your `POST` route:

```php
// Routes should not contains dots.
Route::post('/employees','EmployeeController@store')->name('employee.store');
```

Comment: What is the error message that you got? I guess it has some thing to do with csrf token.